# How to get a request that is not the last in HttPretty?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, httpretty

Using the [HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty) library for Python, I can create mock HTTP responses for my unit tests. When the code I am testing runs, instead of my request reaching the third party, the request is intercepted and my code receives the response I configured.

I then use `last_request()` and can check the url my code requested, any parameters, etc.

What I would like is to know how can I access not just the last request but also any other requests my code sent before the last one.

This seems to be possible. In the documentation it uses a list called `latest_requests`. For example [here](http://httpretty.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=latest)

But that doesn't seem to work for me. I get an AttributeError `AttributeError: module 'httpretty' has no attribute 'latest_requests'`

Here is some code that illustrates what I am trying to do and where I get AttributeError

```
import httpretty
import requests

httpretty.enable()
httpretty.register_uri(
    method=httpretty.GET,
    uri='http://www.firsturl.com',
    status=200,
    body='First Body'
)

httpretty.enable()
httpretty.register_uri(
    method=httpretty.GET,
    uri='http://www.secondurl.com',
    status=200,
    body='secondBody'
)

firstresponse = requests.get('http://www.firsturl.com')
secondresponse = requests.get('http://www.secondurl.com')

print(httpretty.latest_requests[-1].url)

# clean up
httpretty.disable()
httpretty.reset()
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, after reading the docs and attempting to get your code working, I can only describe the documentation as blatantly incorrect. There appear to be [three](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/pull/155) | [separate](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/pull/270) | [pull requests](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/pull/310) from several years ago that claim to make `httpretty.latest_requests` a real attribute but none of them have merged in for whatever reason.

With all of that said, I managed to get the list of all previous requests by calling

```
 httpretty.HTTPretty.latest_requests
```

This returns a list of `HTTPrettyRequest` objects. Seeing as `httpretty.last_request()` returns an `HTTPrettyRequest` object, that attribute is probably what you're looking for.

Unfortunately, `.url` is not defined on that class (but it is [defined on the blank request object](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/blob/2a9e08d96feff10d5d68557f0579b9c6b8d9ebf2/httpretty/core.py#L280) which doesn't make any sense). If you want to check that the request URL is what you're expecting, you pretty much have to try reconstructing it yourself:

```
req = httpretty.HTTPretty.latest_requests[-1]
url = req.headers.get('Host', '') + req.path
```

If you're passing anything in the query string, you'll have to reconstruct that from `req.querystring` although that's not ordered so you probably don't want to turn that into a string for matching purposes. Also, if all of your requests are going to the same domain, you can leave off the host part and just compare `req.path`.